# ComboBox SelectedIndexChanged event fired twice for items with same DisplayMember

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox as below with 3 items ("abc", "abc" & "bbb"). 
The combobox also has AutoCompleteMode "SuggestAppend" & AutoCompleteSource "ListItems" properties. Now I want the text box to show the SelectedIndex of the combobox as below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2TO6.png

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString(); 
    }
```

Everything seems fine until I select the 2nd "abc", the SelectedIndexChanged event will enter for the 1st time & display the index properly on the text box. But when the combobox lost focus, the SelectedIndexChanged event will fire again, causing the index to be displayed wrongly. I found that it only happens to items with the same value. Is there a way I can stop the event from firing twice?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uazYI.png

```
            this.comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
            this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Description"; //Some descriptive field to be shown in combobox
            this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Code"; //Unique code that user won't understand
            this.comboBox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: why having a combobox that contains identical values?

Comment: try e.Handled=true in your selectionchange method

Comment: it's in win form... where can i find my xaml code? :p SelectedIndexChanged doesn't seem to have e.Handled KeyPressArgs?.... I need to have identical values because the uniqueness of the combobox is in "ValueMember" rather than the "DisplayMember"

Comment: try using SelectionChangeCommitted it should only fire once

Comment: SelectionChangeCommitted isn't really suitable because the "DropDownStyle" of the ComboBox is "DropDown", so the index will not change if users type the value in the box

Answer (score 1):

put comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged code in comboBox1_ValueChanged and there u'll get index in event arguments(sender i.e your comboBox cast it in combobox).

use  comboBox1.SelectedIndex and u'll get the index.

Comment: same problem with "SelectedValueChanged" event as i have 2 items with the same value...... I guess the only thing I can do now is to turn off the "AutoCompleteMode" & "AutoCompleteSource" of the combobox =/

Comment: value is the key member is should be unique if its same then it is redundant field and is not a good practice to have. So do create a unique Key.